# How to add multiple terms to a taxonomy via feeds and tamper

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I am importing nodes with taxonomy terms for one vocabulary. I have a set of terms that I would like to use that are set up with their own columns.

I know feeds tamper can explode a set of data in one column using a delimiter and apply that to a term, but I need each taxonomy term to be in it's own column. This is easier for readability for the people who are setting up the database.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Feed Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) gives you a feature to import multivalued field data using any separator like comma(,) using implode plug-in

**If you have csv file like below**

[image]

**You need add implode plugin for that field in tamper tab in feeds form**

[image]

For a detailed tutorial refer this [Awesome link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2287473)!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, it is possible to simply map multiple columns in your csv to the same Taxonomy.

In the Mapping of your importer:

[image: Mapping]

Assuming that you have created the taxonomy "Equipment" (and are adding to it with the import), and Equipment1 and Equipment2 are columns in your csv.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not think this is possible at the moment.

If you map several columns to the same taxonomy term field in a Feeds importer what will happen is that the last input (furthest to the right in the input CSV, or possibly last in the order given in the mapping) will override the previous ones, and only if there is data in that input.  This might be useful in some cases but does not provide the functionality you are looking for.

I think your best bet is to write a new script to implode your columns, and then use tamper to get them into the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is as Sam says, implode the columns into one first with there own delimiter and then import properly.

A dirtier way is to make as many dummy fields as you need on the node so you have something to map each column too then use feeds tamper to implode the mapped fields into your vocab.